Confusion on Struct forward declaration
I have this code on ADT specification of a node
typedef int ElType;
typedef node* Address;

typedef struct node{
    ElType info;
    Address next;
} Node;

Does it going to be the same if i do this?
typedef int ElType;
typedef Node* Address;

typedef struct Node{
    ElType info;
    Address next;
} node;

I don't know where to find explanation about it, so i asked gpt and it says that the second form  wouldn't work because we haven't declare the Node. But the first form could work and the compiler will do a forward-declaration. In my eyes, the only different is the capitalization on it. Could anyone explain it?
Some explanation that could help too understand the topic

Neither is valid

Both are in essence the same (where Node switches parts with node), but as mentioned above both are not valid.

See Is it a good idea to typedef pointers? — TL;DR the answer is usually "No", with an exception for function pointers (which can be very verbose).

Neither is valid so in that sense, they do the same thing. They both fail to compile.
typedef int ElType;
typedef node* Address; // should be "typedef struct node* Address;"

typedef struct node{
    ElType info;
    Address next;
} Node;

typedef int ElType;
typedef Node* Address; // should be "typedef struct Node* Address;"

typedef struct Node{
    ElType info;
    Address next;
} node;

The difference between the two is that you have the types struct node and Node in the first and struct Node and node in the second and that Address is a typedef for a pointer to struct node/struct Node respectively.
An alternative, if you want typedefs, could be:
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node{
    ElType info;
    Node* next;
};

I've here reduced the number of typedefs to the node type to one only as the Address typedef for a pointer-type is likely not going to increase readability of your program. Use struct Node* (or Node* if you use typedefs) since it's very clear what it is.
